# Unable to install Adobe Reader

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader

When I start the installation of Adobe Reader, I get an error message:

> This installer package could not be
>   opened. Verify that the package exist
>   and that you can access it, or contact
>   the application vendor to verify that
>   this is a valid windows installer
>   package.

Why am I getting this error message?

Comment: You should probably provide more information.  What OS are you using?  Exactly what file are you running?  You might need to list the directory contents where the file is.  This could be a permissions problem.

Comment: A heading of "Can any body help me ..." is not very useful.  Always try to have problem-related keywords in your question.

Comment: Exact Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/143786/unable-to-install-adobe-reader

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to get the package with other browser? Try to disable your anti-virus solution when downloading the package?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your download got corrupted. Delete the download file you have, and download a new installer from Adobe : http://get.adobe.com/reader/

When you go to run it, right click and Run-As-Administrator.